# CSV File object to JSON in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, csv

On the front end of my app I wanted to parse some data related to a CSV they upload.  Through the file upload tool, I first get a FileList object and then pull the 1 file out of it.

I want to turn it into a json object which I could then iterate. I was thinking to user csv-parser from node, but I dont see a way to leverage a File object stored in memory.

How Can I accomplish this?

At first I was doing:

```
let f = fileList.item(0);
let decoder = new window.TextDecoder('utf-8');
f.arrayBuffer().then( data => {
   let _data = decoder.decode(data)
   console.log("Dataset", data, _data)
});
```

And that was passing the array buffer, and decoding the string.  While I Could write a generic tool which process this string data based on \n and ',' I wanted this to be a bit more easier to read.

I wanted to do something like:

```
let json = csvParser(f)
```

is there a way to user csv-parser from node, (3.0.0) or is there another tool i should leverage?  I was thinking that levering modules based on the browser ( *new window.TextDecoder(...)* ) is poor form since it has the opportunity to fail.

Is there a tool that does this?  im trying to create some sample data and given a File picked from an input type="file" i would want to have this be simple and straight forward.

This example below works, but i feel the window dependancy and a gut feeling makes me think this is naive.

```
const f : File = fileList.item(0)
console.log("[FOO] File", f)
let decoder = new window.TextDecoder('utf-8');
f.arrayBuffer().then( data => {
    let _data = decoder.decode(data)
    console.log("Dataset", data, _data)
    let lines = _data.split("\n")
    let headers = lines[0].split(',')
    let results = []
    for ( let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
        let line = lines[i]
        let row = {}
        line.split(",").forEach( (item, idx) => {
            row[headers[idx]] = item;
        })
        results.push(row)
    }
    console.log("JSON ARRAY", results)
})
```

The issue i run when i stop and do: `ng serve` is that it does not like using the arrayBuffer function and accessing TextDecoder from window, since that thost functions/classes are not a part of File and window respectively during build.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing, given the file input being passed into this function:

```
updateTranscoders(project: Project, fileList: FileList, choice: string = 'replace') {
    const f: File = fileList.item(0)
        //Reads a File into a string.
        function readToString(file) : Promise<any> {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            const future = new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
                reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
                    resolve(reader.result);
                }, false)
                reader.addEventListener("error", (event) => {
                    console.error("ERROR", event)
                    reject(event)
                }, false)
                reader.readAsText(file)
            }); 
            return future;
        }
        readToString(f).then( data => {
            let lines = data.split("\n")
            let headers = lines[0].split(',')
            let results = []
            for (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
                let line = lines[i]
                let row = {}
                line.split(",").forEach((item, idx) => {
                    row[headers[idx]] = item;
                })
                results.push(row)
            }
            if (choice.toLowerCase() === 'replace'){
                let rows = project.csvListContents.toJson().rows.filter( row => row.isDeployed)
                rows.push( ...results)
                project.csvListContents = CsvDataset.fromJson({ rows: rows })
            }else if (choice.toLowerCase() === 'append') {
                let r = project.csvListContents.toJson();
                r.rows.push(...results);
                project.csvListContents = CsvDataset.fromJson(r);
            }else {
                alert("Invalid option for Choice.")
            }
                
            this.saveProject(project)
        })
    }
```

Now the CHOICE portion of the code is where I have a binary option to do a hard replace on CSV contents or just append to it.  I would then save the project accordingly.   This is also understanding that the first row contains column headers.